# How deal with minimum timings when programming a device?

Tags: c, embedded, state-machine

I am really new to embedded programming, but I've been given a task to write some C code to program a device that I can send commands to (16-bit words). On the specifications sheet that was given to me, theres a section with certain "minimum timings" the device has, such as 'Enable to First Clock Setup Time = 150ns'. There are other timings such as 'Clock width=50ns' etc.

The device has three major pins, EN, CLK, and DATA. The device is initially disabled, and I'm thinking of using state machines to go about sending the command, but I'm confused about the minimum timings.

So my questions are:

-How do I incorporate/compensate for the specified minimum timings listed on the sheet.

-How can I simulate a delay in C?

Comment: Do you control all three pins? You do have some sort of timer in the processor? If you have *no* timer, are there any instructions that take an exact number of clock cycles? Do you know the time of a single clock cycle?

Comment: Assuming the clock is approximately 10MHz I think that means that each clock cycle is about 100ns. I believe I have control to the pins (for now).

Comment: As you state, each clock cycle is ~100ns and the time you need to program is less than 100ns.  So you can probably ignore those min timings.  However, the device probably has a status indication that can be read from the C code.  So read the status to determine if the device is ready for the next command.

Answer (score 2):

These are *minimum timings* - the simplest way of ensuring you are within spec. is to *exceed them*! That is just *take longer* than the minimum - that is easy; it would be hard if these were *maximum* timings.

If the interface is implemented in software, exceeding these timings will be simple in most cases, not only will the processor GPIO have frequency limits that may make timings lower than this unlikely, the CPU instruction cycle time and the number of instructions needed to generate the signals are likely to prevent you getting anywhere close to these minimum timings.

If you are using a hardware communications interface such as SPI to generate the necessary signals then you have much more precise control and it is simply a case of configuring the interface registers to generate the desired *within spec* timing - the chances are you can ignore them; you may need to consider adding delay if your processor and GPIO are *very fast*; but I'd be very surprised if you needed to take any specific action to the timings given.  Delays of a new tens of nanoseconds are best implemented by adding NOP instructions, longer delays perhaps a busy loop polling a timer, or for longer delays still waiting on a timer interrupt while doing something useful.

Critically it is not necessary to *achieve* these minimum timings - merely not to generate signals that are *outside* of the manufacturers specification.